# Spring & Thymeleaf: Refresh single row in table

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I refresh content of a table with:

```
<tr id="rows" th:each="entity: ${entities}">
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
```

and on server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/replace", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String replace(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("entities", entities);
    return "/ :: #rows";
}
```

calling the method with:

```
$.get('/replace', function(fragment) {
    // fragment gives me all rows of the table
}
```

which works as expected. However, I do not want to update all rows every time, but only a single one, so my idea was to use a dynamic `id` as follows:

```
<tr th:id="'row' + ${entity.id}" th:each="entity, iterStat: ${entities}">
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
```

and on server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/replace", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String replace(@RequestParam("id") int id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("entities", entities);
    return "/ :: #row" + id;
}
```

calling the method with:

```
$.get('/replace', {id: id} function(fragment) {
    // fragment is empty
}
```

but that doesn't work. Looking a the html code and server side, the `id` is correct. Is it not possible to use a `th:id`? What would be a workaround if I only want to update one row in a table and not all rows? Thanks.

I also tried the same with `th:fragment` - it works without `${entity.id}` and does not with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to send only one entity to the view with:

```
Entity entity = entityService.findById(id);
model.addAttribute("entities", entity);
```

It is for sure not the prettiest way, but it gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Using `th:fragment` should do the trick. I normally use them to accomplish what you are trying to do. This is an example of how to implement it.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>    
    <th:block th:fragment="entity-row">
        <tr th:id="'row'+${entity.id}">
            <td th:text=${entity.id}></td>
            <!-- Whatever other element you need. -->
        </tr>
    </th:block>
</body>
```

Add the code above in a whole a new html file. Remember, we are expecting one single entity, so we don't need the th:each. Now in order to fetch the fragment, you would need to the following in your Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/replace/fragment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String replaceSingleRow(@RequestParam("id") int id, Model model) {
    Entity entity = entityService.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("entity", entity);
    return "file :: entity-row";
}
```

Where **file** would be the name of the html file that contains the fragment. Of course, I am assuming you are passing only the desired id to our controller.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work..`model.addAttribute("entity", entity);` doesn't return anything.. If I'm returning `model.addAttribute("entities", entities);` I got every row, but with your approach it gives me nothing back..

Comment: Could you show me the file where you are adding your fragment? Also, I would normally add the @ResponseBody in the Controller method, when doing Ajax calls or gets.

Comment: Also, how are you fetching that entity?

Comment: Please look at the question..In html, I have the tr surrounded with the th:fragment..I’m fetching the data with a jQuery get, but the fragment is always empty..

Comment: Ok, so I edited my answer. Please, first add the fragment into a whole new html. So you will have two html files, where one will iterate through all the entities and another that will return a single row. Also, I added the @ResponseBody annotation to your controller method (remember, you have to make a new method in the controller, that will handle this specific call). This should be enough to accomplish what you are looking for. Please, let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your effort..I managed it to do with returning only one sponsor and not the list (with `model.addAttribute("entities", entity);`). I'm sure it is not the most pretty way to do so, but with that I return only the desired entity to the view and from that I can replace the row with jQuery which is enough for me now..anyway thanks for your hints!

Comment: You're welcome! Good to know that you were able to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

Very late response, but I think this is the ultimate solution.

Thymeleaf fragment

```
<tr th:fragment="entity-row" th:id="'row' + ${entity.id}" th:each="entity, iterStat: ${entities}">
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
```

Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/replace", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String replace(@RequestParam("id") int id, Model model) {
    Entity entity = entityService.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("entities", Arrays.asList(entity)); // sending the row as list, so that the loop can iterate and will produce a single row
    return "file :: entity-row";
}
```

You have the desired single row html in your ajax response, now you can replace the existing row

```
$.get('/replace', {id: id} function(fragment) {
    $("#row" + id).replaceWith(fragment);
}
```